# How can i change the texture of a block so it is invisible

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to change the texture of bedrock so that its invisible like an air/ghost block, how can i do this?

I am currently using minecraft 1.7.2

Comment: What are you needing it for?

Comment: I want to create an unbreakable wall for a survival map i'm building but i want it to be completely invivisble

Comment: If you use the snapshots, you can use [barrier blocks](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Barrier) - they are created for that exact purpose.

Comment: I am using 1.7.2 will update my question

Comment: Simply find the texture file (a .png file) and make the bedrock block transparent using an image editor that supports transparency.

Comment: @Kcats you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a program such as gimp or even paint, then locate the main texture for blocks which should be located in .minecraft/bin/minecraft.jar/assets/minecraft/textures. After you find whichever .png file you wish to edit, extract it and open it in one of the two image editing programs. Find the texture for the block you wish to edit and erase it. Make sure not to erase any of the nearby blocks because if you are replacing the .png it will be permanent. Just in case back up the original .png. If you cannot locate the default texture using this method then a simple google search should help you find it.

Also, please note that if you do do this, there will be a bit of a glitch that makes you kinda "see" through the world if the bedrock is placed next to a nearby block. This shouldn't really heppen though since bedrock isn't usually obtainable in survival. If in creative then you have been warned.

Also please note that in future updates, mojang will be introducing invisible barriers for adventure maps.